# 2 different color text in one cell

Tags: vbscript, outlook

We are putting together a new standard signature using vbs for Outlook.
Everything looks great but design would like the phone numbers to look like the attached image.  The "O" for office # in Orange and then the number in blue, the "C" for cell # in Orange and then the number in blue.
I can get the entire cell to be one color, but I don't see how to do 2 colors.
The signature is in a table with the logo in one cell that has 5 rows merged and then the other side has 5 rows.

[image: ImageOfNewSignatureForOutlook]

Here is some of my code:

```
strName = objUser.FullName
strTitle = objUser.Title
strPhone = objUser.telephoneNumber
strMobile = objUser.mobile  
strOffice = "O " 
strCell = "C "

objTable.Cell(3,2).Range.Font.Name = "Lato"
objTable.Cell(3,2).Range.Font.Size = "12"
objTable.Cell(3,2).Range.Text = strOffice & strPhone & "    " & strCell & strMobile
```

Answer (score 0):

Start recording a macro do it manually by editing the in the cell or the formula bar.  Stop the macro and step into it to get all the colors. I stuck to the main colors on the bottom of the pallet. You'll may have to track ThemeColor, TintAndShade and ThemeFont depending on the colors you choose.

This should get you started

```
Public Sub AddLogo(r As Range)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ColorArray
    ColorArray = Array(-16777024, -16776961, -16727809, -16711681, -11480942, -11489280, -1003520, -4165632, -10477568, -6279056)
    r = "Excel Magic"

    For i = 0 To UBound(ColorArray)
        With r.Characters(Start:=(i + 1), Length:=1).Font
             .Color = ColorArray(i)
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

**Usage:**

> AddLogo objTable.Cell(3,2)